# Log inside directory not the same outside directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

My project structure is like that :

```
|--projects
  |--scanner-app
    |--main.py
```

So If I run my script from the `scanner-app` (`amine@amine ~/scanner-app $ python main.py`) I got log in the console like that :

```
2018-08-01 11:46:54,368 - root - INFO - Script Started
```

But when I run the script from `projects` directory (`amine@amine ~/projects $ python scanner-app/main.py`) here is what I receive:

```
INFO:root:Script Started
```

This is my config file :

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": false,
    "formatters": {
        "simple": {
            "format": "%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
        }
    },
    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "formatter": "simple",
            "stream": "ext://sys.stdout"
        },
        "info_file_handler": {
            "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
            "level": "INFO",
            "formatter": "simple",
            "filename": "info.log",
            "maxBytes": 10485760,
            "backupCount": 20,
            "encoding": "utf8"
        },
        "error_file_handler": {
            "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
            "level": "ERROR",
            "formatter": "simple",
            "filename": "errors.log",
            "maxBytes": 10485760,
            "backupCount": 20,
            "encoding": "utf8"
        }
    },
    "loggers": {
        "my_module": {
            "level": "ERROR",
            "handlers": ["console"],
            "propagate": "no"
        }
    },
    "root": {
        "level": "INFO",
        "handlers": ["console", "info_file_handler", "error_file_handler"]
    }
}
```

And finally my fucntion that call the json file to configure the log :

```
def setup_logging(
        default_path='logging.json',
        default_level=logging.DEBUG,
        env_key='LOG_CFG'
):
    """Setup logging configuration

    """
    path = default_path
    value = os.getenv(env_key, None)
    if value:
        path = value
    if os.path.exists(path):
        with open(path, 'rt') as f:
            config = json.load(f)
        logging.config.dictConfig(config)
    else:
        logging.basicConfig(level=default_level)
```

I call my fucntion like that :

```
setup_logging('logging.json', logging.DEBUG, 'LOG_CFG')
```

I have 3 questions :

1. Why I have 2 type of logs here ?
2. In the second case when I run the script outside the root directory
   (`scanner-app`) I got some additional log (the logs of some
   libraries I use) why this happen ?
3. Is it possible to have the log like the first case plus the log of
   the libraries in the 2 cases inside the root directory and outside ?

Comment: _Why I have 2 type of logs here ?_ Because most probably you are calling `setup_logging()` without parameters, and `logging.json` can be resolved only in the `scanner-app` dir. Relative paths are resolved by the current directory; the more robust solution is to resolve the file paths relative to `__file__`.

Comment: _In the second case when I run the script outside the root directory (scanner-app) I got some additional log (the logs of some libraries I use) why this happen ?_ Same story - `logging.basicConfig(level=DEBUG)` will configure you a different logger that will also log debug records from involved libraries.

Comment: _Is it possible to have the log like the first case plus the log of the libraries in the 2 cases inside the root directory and outside ?_ Resolve the `logging.json` file relative to `__file__` and remove the `else` block and you should be good to go.

Comment: @hoefling Thanks a lot for this helpful comments, just one thing I didn't get it the thing with `__file__` can you be more specific (I added how to I call the function in my question)

Comment: Resolve `default_path` in `setup_logging` like this: `path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), default_path)`. This will give you the path `/path/to/module.py/../logging.json`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. `os.path.dirname(__file__)` return emty I change it to `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` and it worked I get the absolute path, but now I can't get the logs of the libraries I mean even in my second case when I execute the script outside the directory there is no logs of the libraries, any idea why ?

Comment: I Found it, It's just to change `INFO` to `DEBUG` in the root node in the json file, Thanks a lot any way